# Three.js within web worker: Simulating animation without rendering to canvas

Tags: three.js, web-worker, device-orientation

I have a hypothetical question:

Is it possible to simulate an animation of objects without rendering it to the canvas. I just want to capture objects' position using `Vector.project(camera)` and present it using CSS. And `THREE.DeviceOrientationControls` controls how the camera "view" the simulation.

I tried commenting `THREE.WebGLRenderer`, but it seems that `THREE.PerpectiveCamera` cannot update it's `MatrixWorld` property. Hence, the camera seems to not move and the `Vector.project(camera)` gives a static value. I do this because I need to put my three.js codes within a web worker.

Do I need still need to use `THREE.WebGLRenderer` to have a working simulation?

UPDATE:

I checked the following:

- I digged deeper into `((three.scene.getObjectByName("one")).matrixWorld.getPosition()).project(three.camera);`, I inspect the following values, having the above requirement (inside web worker, no renderer), using [this](http://zachberry.com/blog/tracking-3d-objects-in-2d-with-three-js/) example:

> ```
> matrix: {"elements":{"0":3.2167603969573975,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":2.1445069313049316,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":-1.000100016593933,"11":-1,"12":5.4684929847717285,"13":2.1445069313049316,"14":-0.2000100016593933,"15":0}}
> camera.projectionMatrix: {"elements":{"0":3.2167603969573975,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":2.1445069313049316,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":-1.000100016593933,"11":-1,"12":0,"13":0,"14":-0.2000100016593933,"15":0}}
> camera.matrixWorld: {"elements":{"0":1,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":1,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":1,"11":0,"12":-1.7000000476837158,"13":-1,"14":0,"15":1}}
> matrix.getInverse(camera.matrixWorld): {"elements":{"0":1,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":1,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":1,"11":0,"12":1.7000000476837158,"13":1,"14":0,"15":1}}
> matrix.multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, matrix.getInverse(camera.matrixWorld)): {"elements":{"0":3.2167603969573975,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":2.1445069313049316,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":-1.000100016593933,"11":-1,"12":5.4684929847717285,"13":2.1445069313049316,"14":-0.2000100016593933,"15":0}}
> ```

- But, when normal (no modification), I inspect the following:

> 

```
matrix: {"elements":{"0":3.2167603969573975,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":2.1445069313049316,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":-1.000100016593933,"11":-1,"12":5.4684929847717285,"13":2.1445069313049316,"14":-0.2000100016593933,"15":0}}
camera.projectionMatrix: {"elements":{"0":3.2167603969573975,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":2.1445069313049316,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":-1.000100016593933,"11":-1,"12":0,"13":0,"14":-0.2000100016593933,"15":0}}
camera.matrixWorld: {"elements":{"0":1,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":-2.220446049250313e-16,"6":-1,"7":0,"8":0,"9":1,"10":-2.220446049250313e-16,"11":0,"12":-1.7000000476837158,"13":-1,"14":0,"15":1}}
matrix.getInverse(camera.matrixWorld): {"elements":{"0":1,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":-2.220446049250313e-16,"6":1,"7":0,"8":0,"9":-1,"10":-2.220446049250313e-16,"11":0,"12":1.7000000476837158,"13":-2.220446049250313e-16,"14":1,"15":1}}
matrix.multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, matrix.getInverse(camera.matrixWorld)): {"elements":{"0":3.2167603969573975,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":-4.761761943205948e-16,"6":-1.000100016593933,"7":-1,"8":0,"9":-2.1445069313049316,"10":2.2206681307011713e-16,"11":2.220446049250313e-16,"12":5.4684929847717285,"13":-4.761761943205948e-16,"14":-1.2001099586486816,"15":-1}}
```

I noticed that the `camera.matrixWorld` property has significant difference in both condition. I do not understand what makes the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the following lines from THREE.WebGLRenderer.render are still needed to update `camera.matrixWorld` property:

```
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
camera.updateMatrixWorld();
camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse(vs._3.camera.matrixWorld);
```